# Why modern ES over browser supported ES

Tags: javascript, browser

Javascript frameworks transpile's code from modern ES to browser supported ES, Why are we doing source-to-source compile while we can achive same with browser supported ES version

Comment: I'd recommend stepping out of the mindset of "fewer lines of code" and into the mindset of "more concise and expressive code which keeps the focus on the logic being performed without cluttering it with the structures used to perform that logic".

Comment: ES6 is almost 6 years old. ES5 is almost 12 years old. If you ask me, we shouldn't target either.

Comment: People transpile their code when they want it to be able to run in an environment that might not support all the latest language features and they don't want to have to worry about restricting their programming to just things that they know are supported in every single browser.  Otherwise, you have to figure out what is the least common denominator feature set for all your target browsers and make absolutely sure you don't use some feature that isn't in that least common denominator subset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People transpile their code when they want it to be able to run in an environment that might not support all the latest language features and they don't want to have to worry about restricting their programming to just things that they know are supported in every single possible browser a client might use.

Otherwise, you have to figure out what is the least common denominator feature set for all your target browsers and make absolutely sure you don't use some feature that isn't in that least common denominator subset.

And, with transpiling you are safe to use even the very newest language features (as long as the transpiler supports them) without even waiting for browser support at all.  A nice thing about transpiling is that you can decide what target environment is safe for all the target environments you want to run in and you can transpile for that target.  For example, if you now think that ES6 is a safe transpiler target, you can set the transpilation target to ES6, yet you can still use much newer language features in your code.  When you think ES7 has become a safe target, you can change your tranpiler target forward and generate more efficient ES7-based code.  Meanwhile, you didn't have to change your original code at all which you were able to write to the latest, modern standards from the beginning.

Answer (score -2):

Here is an example with a function:

```
// ES5
function greetings (name) {
   return 'hello ' + name
 }
// ES6
const greetings = (name) => {
  return `hello ${name}`;
}
```

So even if you can achieve the same result with ES5, it isn´t as clean as with ES6

Comment: This is not the point at all of ES6.  It's not about saving a few characters of typing.  I would argue the ES5 example here is much clearer in this specific case.  Arrow functions have very valuable uses - this is not even in the top 5 of the reasons to use them.  Template literals are very useful, though this example doesn't really show them to much advantage.

Comment: Ok if you prefer to have a nasty code, that´s fine.

Comment: How is your ES5 example "nasty code"?  There's nothing at all wrong with that and it's quite arguable that the `function` declaration in the ES5 example is clearer to read than the second.

Comment: And what about the template literals? And the destructuring assignment? And all the other features? They make the code a lot cleaner indeed.

Comment: I would much rather program using ES8 features than ES5 features.  I was commenting on your specific example you offered as I think that's a crummy example.  I don't even think a const arrow function definition is more desirable than a standard `function` declaration.  So, not only did you not pick good and compelling reasons, but I don't even agree with the example you did pick.  But, I don't think this is quite what the OP was asking.  If you edit your question slightly, I will then be allowed to remove my downvote and I'll just let my comments speak for my opinion.